# How do I update a record on a Scheduled Apex Class?

Tags: apex, scheduled-apex, scheduled-job

I'm running into issues with the format of a Scheduled Apex Class. This will be my first time I've done it. The issue is with setting the PhotoUrls and updating the employee. I also don't think my for loop is running as my debug doesn't show in the log either. However I've tried running it without the if statements after the for and it still doesn't run. Any suggestions on a fix would be great.

```
global class EmployeeProfileImageUpdateHandler implements Schedulable {

global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {
    Set<Id> employeeset = new set<Id>();       
    List <SFDC_Employee__c> employees = [SELECT Id, FullPhotoUrl__c, SmallPhotoUrl__c, Employee_User__c FROM SFDC_Employee__c]; 
    for(SFDC_Employee__c employee : employees) {  
        employeeset.add(employee.Id);
    }  
    User[] photos = [Select ID, FullPhotoUrl, SmallPhotoUrl From User where ID IN :employeeset];
    Map<String, User> photomap = new Map<String, User>();
    for (User photo : photos) {
        photomap.put(photo.ID,photo); 
    }

    for(SFDC_Employee__c employee : employees) {
        for (User photo : photos) {
            if(photo.Id == employee.Employee_User__c) {
                if(photomap.containskey(photo.ID)) {
                    employee.FullPhotoUrl__c = photomap.get(photo.Id).FullPhotoUrl;
                    employee.SmallPhotoUrl__c = photomap.get(photo.Id).SmallPhotoUrl;
                    update employee;

                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'Full Photo Url:' +  employee.FullPhotoUrl__c);
                    System.debug(LoggingLevel.DEBUG, 'Small Photo Url:' +  employee.SmallPhotoUrl__c);
                }               
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because in your for loop you are adding the Id field where you need to add `Employee_User__c`

```
for(SFDC_Employee__c employee : employees) {  
        employeeset.add(employee.Id);
    }
```

change this into

```
for(SFDC_Employee__c employee : employees) {  
        employeeset.add(employee.Employee_User__c);
    }
```

Also you can directly query in map

```
Map<Id, User> photomap = new Map<Id, User>( [Select ID, FullPhotoUrl, SmallPhotoUrl From User where ID IN :employeeset]);
```

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Tushar's answer.

Here is a version with a bit more change made:

```
global void execute(SchedulableContext ctx) {

    // TODO Governor limit risk here as number of employees grows
    Set<Id> userIds = new Set<Id>();       
    SFDC_Employee__c[] employees = [
            SELECT Employee_User__c
            FROM SFDC_Employee__c
            ]; 
    for(SFDC_Employee__c e : employees) userIds(e.Employee_User__c);

    Map<Id, User> users = new Map<Id, User>([
            Select ID, FullPhotoUrl, SmallPhotoUrl
            From User
            where ID IN :userIds
            ];

    SFDC_Employee__c[] updates = new SFDC_Employee__c[] {};
    for(SFDC_Employee__c e : employees) {
        User u = users.get(e.Employee_User__c));
        if (u != null) {
            if (e.FullPhotoUrl__c != u.FullPhotoUrl || e.SmallPhotoUrl__c != u.SmallPhotoUrl) {
                updates.add(new SFDC_Employee__c(
                        Id = e.Id,
                        FullPhotoUrl__c = u.FullPhotoUrl,
                        SmallPhotoUrl__c = u.SmallPhotoUrl
                        ));
            }
        }
    }
    update updates;
}
```

This bulkifies the update and only does the update when it is needed. It also gets rid of the double nested loop that would cause the CPU time to grow exponentially as the number of rows grew.

Comment: As you have created new instance so you should add ID as well.

Comment: @TusharSharma Woops yes. I've added that to the code. Thanks.